# How to perform a MANCOVA in R

Tags: r, multivariate-analysis, mancova

I have been looking around and cannot figure out how to perform a Mancova in R. 
independent variable: cluster number
dependent variables (multivariate): body shape (19 partial warp scores)
covariate: sex/gender (either male or female)

I am trying to determine if body shape is dependent on cluster number but, an issue of sexual dimorphism in males and females creates a covariate of gender. I want to account for the effects of gender on body shape by performing the mancova. I have not been able to find clear information on how to perform a mancova in R.